# Get Generic Type in ListView Item

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a custom control that will allow me to drag and drop between controls. I am following [This](http://www.wpftutorial.net/draganddrop.html) that gets me all the way there until I want to allow for multiple types. So I may want to use this in a customers form and drag between two customer `ListViews`, or an `Employee` form and drag between two employee forms.

For some reason I cannot cast as `Type`. Please explain where I am going wrong and why. Thank you!

```
    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = _startPoint - mousePos;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
            Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
            Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
        {
            if (ListView != null)
            {
                ListViewItem listViewItem =
                    FindAnchestor<ListViewItem>((DependencyObject) e.OriginalSource);
                Type itemType = ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(listViewItem).GetType();
                var item = (itemType)ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(listViewItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please explain where I am going wrong and why.

You are trying to *statically* cast to a *dynamically* determined type.

The bad news: That doesn't work. Static types must be known at compile time.

The good news: There's absolutely no *need* to do this: For your purposes, storing the reference in a generic object variable suffices:

```
object item = ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(listViewItem);
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I think that I should check on drop that it is the same type? if so, how can i do this?

Comment: @JamTay317: The same type as what?

Comment: I want to ensure that the listview that I am dragging from (lets say that the itemSource IEnumerable<Dog>) and the listView i am dragging to has an ItemSource IEnumerable<Dog> and not IEnumerable<Cat>

Comment: @JamTay317: I don't think that this is easily possible, since the ListView does not have an "item type". It just happens that you, while data binding, supplied an `IEnumerable<Dog>`, and the ListView happily accepted your dogs. It will also happily accept a cat, if you add one to it. I guess the simplest solution would be to hard-code which ListViews are "drag-and-drop-compatible" and check for that.

Comment: Thank you I will post result in here once i create drag-and-drop-compatible.